# How do I change jquery_update version for a custom theme?

Tags: 7, javascript

There are two options in jquery_update module's configuration: Jquery to be used in frontend theme, and Jquery to be used in admin themes. I set another theme to be used by a specific role (say, manager).
How do I change jquery_update version of that theme that is used by manager role.
Is it possible to do this with template.php, if yes, how so?

I already followed a patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1524944), but I am not sure if I should apply that old patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a patch, [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) 7.x-3.0-alpha5 works great and it already includes functionality to specify jquery version per theme (as per this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update/issues/1969244)) on configuration page `admin/config/development/jquery_update`

[image]

For specifying a theme per role you can try any of the following modules [role_theme_switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) [Themes By Role (TBR)](https://www.drupal.org/project/tbr)